# Validacion JavaScript, formulario HTML

Tags: javascript, html, formularios, dom

Tengo esta función para validar un `input type="text"` de un formulario. Pero me sale el error:

> Cannot read property 'value' of null

```
function compruebaCodigo() {

    //Que el código tiene dos letras.
    var campoCodigo = document.getElementById("codigo").value;
    var normaCodigo = /[A-Z]{2}/;

    var validaCodigo;

    if (normaCodigo.test(campoCodigo)) {
        validaCodigo = true;
    } else {
        validaCodigo = false;
    }

    return validaCodigo;
}
```

**Mi JS completo es este:**

```
window.addEventListener("load",cargaPagina);


var misPaises= new ListaPaises();

function cargaPagina() { 

    document.getElementById("enviar").addEventListener("click", compruebaCodigo);
    document.getElementById("enviar").addEventListener("click", compruebaPoblacion);
    document.getElementById("enviar").addEventListener("click", todosCamposIntroducidos);

}

function compruebaCodigo() {

    //Que el código tiene dos letras.
    var campoCodigo = document.getElementById("codigo").value;
    var normaCodigo = /[A-Z]{2}/;

    var validaCodigo;

    if (normaCodigo.test(campoCodigo)) {
        validaCodigo = true;
    } else {
        validaCodigo = false;
    }

    return validaCodigo;
}

function compruebaPoblacion() { 

        //Que el código tiene dos letras.
    var campoPoblacion = document.getElementById("poblacion").value;
    var normaPoblacion = /\d/;

    var validaPoblacion;

    if (normaPoblacion.test(campoPoblacion)) {
        validaPoblacion = true;
    } else {
        validaPoblacion = false;
    }

    return validaPoblacion;

}


function todosCamposIntroducidos() { 

    var campoCodigo = document.getElementById("codigo").value;
    var campoPoblacion = document.getElementById("poblacion").value;

    var validacion;

    if(campoCodigo!=="" && campoPoblacion!=="") { 
        validacion=true;
    }else{ 
        validacion=false;
    }

    return validacion;
}

function comprobaciones() { 

    var codigoValidado=compruebaCodigo();
    var poblacionValidada=compruebaPoblacion();
    var camposValidados=todosCamposIntroducidos();

    var paisListo;

    if (codigoValidado===true && poblacionValidada===true && camposValidados===true){
        paisListo=true;
    }else{
        paisListo=false;
    }

    return paisListo;
}


if (comprobaciones()===true) {
    var miPais1=new Pais(document.getElementById("codigo").value,document.getElementById("nombre").value,document.getElementById("poblacion")).value;
}

misPaises[miPais1];
```

Comment: Tiene pinta de que el motivo es que el `input` no tiene como `id` "codigo"

Comment: @AsierVillanueva el input te tengo asi: `<input type="text" id="codigo" />`

Comment: Puedes mostrar en que momento ejecutas compruebaCodigo() ?

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el HTML, por favor? Así nos podemos hacer una idea mejor :-) Gracias!